# Could my question(s) be reopened?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I made a small goof.

I asked two hardware questions about Keyboards and Mice.  The questions are very similar and, accidentally, I typed in the same title for both (referencing keyboards.)

These questions managed to get put on hold and flagged as duplicates.  I've updated the questions and fixed my errors.  Could I have them re-opened?

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245126/best-keyboard-for-a-windows-developer-who-uses-os-xparallels
- [Best mouse for a Windows Developer who uses OS X+Parallels](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245127/best-mouse-for-a-windows-developer-who-uses-os-xparallels)

Answer (score 4):

These questions will, unfortunately, remain closed, for two reasons:

1. Both are shopping questions and [shopping questions are off topic for Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You're asking for a purchase recommendation in both questions. Shopping or buying recommendations. Questions that are mainly about price/time/supply constraints are considered "shopping" questions.
2. Both are asking for "best" options. While you do give some criteria for filtering purchase options, "best" is ultimately *very* subjective in these cases and as such there's no, real, canonical answer that can be given and that's not what Stack Exchange is about when it comes to Q&A.

Ultimately these questions are better suited for a traditional discussion forum format. You can find something akin to this in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) or take advantage of an existing forum like https://www.reddit.com/r/apple.

Comment: My definition of "best" isn't subjective, really.  I think the implicationnis clear, is there hardware that functiona best in both environments.  I'll remove the parts about pricing when I get a chance.

Comment: A standard keyboard works *best* in both environments, as does a plain vanilla mouse :-) Or in other words: without a clear indication about what "best" means for you and how you want to measure it, "best" always is subjective.